# Switch to Cloudfront CDN causing issues for small number of users

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

We've got an AWS EC2 hosted site, and we're trying to add a CloudFront Distribution infront of it.  Everything works fine in our staging environment, but when we pointed the production DNS to CloudFront, a handful of users complained that the site would no longer load.

I realize this is lacking in detail, but it's all the detail I have, so just wondering if there are any obvious things I should be checking.

The CF Distribution didn't introduce any WAF rules, so it shouldn't be filtering anyone out.  And it's set up to cache a single assets folder, and just proxy everything else back to the origin.

There's no noticeable change in traffic volume or any errors in our logs, and we can verify everything works from our devices.

Comment: Please check if the EC2 resources(CPU, Memory, Network, Storage, or any external resources like DB connections and concurrency) are enough to handle the requests by checking the CloudWatch Monitoring. There is a chance that some requests may not be cached, and it is being processed by the server each time taking the I/O. Also, check if there is any logs in EC2 application and see whether any request takes huge time to process.